# Is there any method to write Sweet Alert confirmation box in Controller?

Tags: laravel-5

```
Alert::success('Category deleted successfully', 'Success')->persistent("Close");
```

I want to add an alert for confirmation to user in Controller, how can i do that? Is that possible?

Comment: Are you asking if it is possible to fire a client side javascript event in server side php code?

Comment: In Laravel Controller.

Comment: I am not clear what you're asking. Laravel is a server side language, sweetalert is a client side javascript library.

Comment: Ikr. I just want to know whether i can write an alert for confirmation during perform some action in controller to alert user instead of do it in blade template.